# WSO2 ESB: AxisFault: no protocol

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I'm having a problem with the following proxy in WSO2 ESB 4.6.0:

```
<proxy name="GetCapacity" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
  <target>
     <inSequence>
        <xslt key="conf:ManageWorkforce/xslt/GetCapacity_Request.xsl"/>
        <send>
           <endpoint key="Capacity"/>
        </send>
     </inSequence>
     <outSequence>
        <filter xpath="get-property('FAULT')">
           <then>
              <log level="full" separator=",">
                 <property name="trace" value="-------- FAULT ---------"/>
              </log>
              <xslt key="conf:ManageWorkforce/xslt/SoapFaultToStandardHeader.xsl"/>
              <header name="To" expression="get-property('ReplyTo')"/>
           </then>
           <else>
              <xslt key="conf:ManageWorkforce/xslt/GetCapacity_Response.xsl"/>
           </else>
        </filter>
        <send/>
     </outSequence>
     <faultSequence>
        <log level="full" separator=",">
           <property name="trace" value="-------- FAULT SEQUENCE -------"/>
        </log>
        <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
        <header name="To" expression="get-property('ReplyTo')"/>
     </faultSequence>
  </target>
</proxy>
```

When I call it with soapUI and the Service throws a SoapFault (the FAULT property is TRUE), the following error occurs in WSO2:

```
[2014-01-20 19:13:30,764] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error sending message back
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: no protocol: 
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:453)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:277)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:161)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:282)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:92)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:230)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:443)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.send(DynamicAxisOperation.java:238)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.DynamicAxisOperation$DynamicOperationClient.executeImpl(DynamicAxisOperation.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:456)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:57)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:316)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:329)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:59)
    at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.IndirectEndpoint.send(IndirectEndpoint.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:422)
    ... 31 more
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error it seems to be that the "To" header is incorrect. Could you please try to remove the "To" header and see. In your configuration "To" header has been add using "ReplyTo" property.  Therefore Please add following in to your fault sequence

```
<header name="To" action="remove"/>
```

Also, It is better to enable the debug logs,  to troubleshoot the issues. This would show you messages in the wire. Please enable following two properties from log4j.properties file which can be found at /repository/conf directory.

> log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.wire=DEBUG
>   log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.headers=DEBUG

Add more in the answer, You have copied "To" header from the "ReplyTo". You can log the value of the "ReplyTo" as following to check whether it is actually incorrect.

```
<log level="custom"><property name="RelyTo" expression="get-property('ReplyTo')"/></log>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer Asela. I've removed the `To`, but now this happens: `org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Both the TO and MessageContext.TRANSPORT_OUT property are null, so nowhere to send`

Comment: Hmm  shall we verify whether,

Comment: Sorry.. I added some more in the answer. please check. It is better to verify your "ReplyTo" value.  Or else just remove the  <header> property from the out sequence and see.

Comment: I've removed. The error is the same described in the first comment above.

Comment: Right after the SoapFault: `To = http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous,From = ,Action = ,ReplyTo = ,FaultTo = `. Then I remove the `To` and `<send/>`

Comment: From the error trace what I can observe is you have used the servlet transport instead of default passthrough transport. Could you answer the following questions. 1. How do you invoke the proxy service (service url) ? 2. Have you done any modifications to the default axis2.xml ? If so what are the modifications ?

Comment: You also don't need the following config line.

     <header name="To" expression="get-property('ReplyTo')"/>

Instead of that put following configuration to send fault back to client.

   <header name="To" action="remove"/>
   <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>           <!-- you already have this -->
   <send/>